# Using dependecy injection the right way

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I'm using Autofac to implement IoC in my solution, But I am doubtful whether I'm doing it right or not. Here's the scenario:
I have some `Manager` classes which all derive from `BaseManager` class. The `BaseManager` has a `protected User CurrentUser` field.  What I'm trying to do, is to resolve the `CurrentUser` using Autofac. I have written an`IUserProvider` interface and implemented a couple of classes (e.g. `WebUserProvider` and `WinformsUserProvider`).
Then I registered my provider as below (for example, in `Global.asax)`:

```
builder.Register(c => new WebUserProvider(...)).As<IUserProvider>();
```

- How can I resolve dependencies (access `container` in my classes)? I could use a singleton or a service locator pattern but seems like it's an [anti-pattern](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container). So how should I resolve my dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like overengineering to me. Why would you have a *base manager* class  that has knowledge of the user? Having *a few manager* classes is a code smell and a maintenance hazard on its own, as your are abstracting too much. Do you *really* need that?

> How can I resolve dependencies (access container in my classes)?

You should not be looking for a way to access your container. Container *must* be initialized once, in a single place. You should inject all the dependencies via constructor. These dependencies are passed in from the root of the dependency graph using `container.Resolve<T>` and elsewhere in the dependency graph using constructor injection (or some folks use property injection).

Comment: I had to define BaseManager and initialize CurrentUser there, because of logging purposes. (I didn't want to pass current user to every method in my manager classes.) You said "Container must be initialized once, in a single place", So if Service Locator and singleton are anti patterns, what is left to initialize and access a single container?

Comment: If this is a WinForms app, you can create and set up your container somewhere close to the point of entry (main method). In the main as well you resolve an interface and pass it in to the members.  In ASP.NET you can set it up in a global.asax and then register a factory, for example like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124393/setting-up-inversion-of-control-ioc-in-asp-net-mvc-with-castle-windsor). So with DI and IoC all the dependent classes have their abstractions injected and never explicitly requested.